# Workflow to write article with orgmode/babel when knowing LaTeX

Tags: errors, babel, org-mode

I know LaTeX pretty well and I am used to write articles with it.
I know orgmode and use it to manage my todo list and research notes.
I am trying to learn the babel module of orgmode, so that to write litterate programming articles where the algorithms are real codes and the examples are automatically computed.

When the orgmode export encounters an error, I generate the LaTeX file, compile it and see the error code produced, to then debug the babel source. Is there a more direct way to see the error produced by the compilation of the latex code automatically generated by the export?

I am using Org-mode version 7.9.3e and am reluctant to switch over to a more recent version before I have the time to revisit my configuration entirely :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your approach is not unreasonable.  As an alternative, you can set the variable `org-latex-remove-logfiles` to `nil`, and then the `.log` and other files will be available in the file's directory for you to examine for errors and warnings.  The variable can be set via customize.  The description of this variable says:

> ```
> Documentation:
> Non-nil means remove the logfiles produced by PDF production.
> By default, logfiles are files with these extensions: .aux, .idx,
> .log, .out, .toc, .nav, .snm and .vrb.  To define the set of
> logfiles to remove, set `org-latex-logfiles-extensions'.
> ```

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping for a better workflow (similar to auctex when compiling latex), but I realize that it is far from trivial to implement.